# Заявка принята или зарегистрирована?

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно:
"Заявка принята" или "зарегистрирована"?
И почему?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему здесь разный смысл, по-крайней мере, формально. Если заявка принята - она принята к исполнению. А зарегистрирована - внесена в определенный реестр, а вот будет ли она выполняяться или только рассматриваться (скажем, на предмет законности, финансовых возможностей и т.п.) - это вопрос открытый.

Answer (score 0):

заявка принята. зарегистрирована в журнале